# Code igniter url segment

Tags: codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-url

currently my website url is 
https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/main/inside?id=8
but I want this to be like this 
https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/nfl
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the application/config/routes.php file and add a new route for it

```
$route['nfl'] = 'main/inside';
```

It should be as simple as that :)

See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html for more examples.

### Edit

I've worked with CI for a long time and I've never seen it use GET params in the routes file in that way. I'm not sure it is possible.

You could have it like `$route['nfl'] = 'main/inside/8';`

then in the main controller your inside method would look like:

```
public function inside($id)
{
    //$id would contain the ID of 8 when you go to 
    //https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/main/inside/8
    //or https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/nfl
}
```

Comment: I want this url
https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/nfl
from this
https://www.thefoolsbookie.com/main/inside?id=8

according to your code, I use like this in route.php
$route['nfl'] = 'main/inside?id=8';

Comment: see the changes that I've made in the answer